# How can I store question data for use in my app?

Tags: wordpress, react-native

I need to store question data in a cms like `wordpress`, and use a `json` endpoint to pull into my app. Something like this:

```
<question>
What event marked the start of World War II?
</question>
<correct_answer>
Invasion of Poland (1939)
</correct_answer>
<incorrect_answers>
["Invasion of Russia (1942)","Battle of Britain (1940)","Invasion of Normandy (1944)"]
</incorrect_answers>
```

The problem is the resulting json looks like this, `wordpress` inserts line breaks and paragrpahs:

```
<p><question><br \/>\nWhat event marked the start of World War II?<br \/>\n<\/question><br \/>\n<correct_answer><br \/>\nInvasion of Poland (1939)<br \/>\n<\/correct_answer><br \/>\n<incorrect_answers><br \/>\n[“Invasion of Russia (1942)”,”Battle of Britain (1940)”,”Invasion of Normandy (1944)”]<br \/>\n<\/incorrect_answers><br \/>\n<question><br \/>\ntesting<br \/>\n<\/question><br \/>\n<correct_answer><br \/>\nyseesf<br \/>\n<\/correct_answer><br \/>\n<incorrect_answers><br \/>\n[“gffdg”,”fdgfdg”,”dfgfdgfd”]<br \/>\n<\/incorrect_answers><\/p>\n","protected":false},"excerpt":{"rendered":"<p>What event marked the start of World War II? Invasion of Poland (1939) [“Invasion of Russia (1942)”,”Battle of Britain (1940)”,”Invasion of Normandy (1944)”] testing yseesf [“gffdg”,”fdgfdg”,”dfgfdgfd”]<\/p>\n
```

How can I use a store data like this in a more accessible way?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you need to parse it into a JSON format and then you use it easily. Use this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-xml2js

Answer (score 0):

PHP part

```
$questions = array(
    array(
        'question' = 'What event marked the start of World War II?',
        'answers' = array('Invasion of Russia (1942)', 'Invasion of Poland (1939)', 'Battle of Britain (1940', 'Invasion of Normandy (1944)'),
        'correct_answer' = 1
    ),
    array(
        'question' = 'Question 2',
        'answers' = array('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'),
        'correct_answer' = 0
    )
);

$json = json_encode($questions);
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'questions', $json);
```